# How to fix 'BOOM! Could not generate outside point' error when using ST_Distance_Spheroid with different SRS in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, spatial-query

I am trying to calculate the nearest feature distance from a point using PostGIS **ST_Distance_Spheroid** function.

**Case 1:**

The point and the feature collection are in the same SRS and I am expecting the distance to be in meters.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   ST_DistanceSpheroid(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]' ) AS distance_m 
FROM green_belt
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326) 
LIMIT 1;
```

The above query is working as expected. Here is the result:

[image: first query result]

**Case 2:**

When the SRS are different for the point and the feature collection, I am using the below query:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    ST_DistanceSpheroid(geom, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326), 27700), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]' ) AS distance_m 
FROM aonb
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326), 27700) 
LIMIT 1;
```

But in this case, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  BOOM! Could not generate outside point!
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_distance_spheroid" statement 2
SQL state: XX000
```

I even tried by transforming the coordinates and use it in the first query to get the distance:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    ST_DistanceSpheroid(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(357980.44 331724.97)', 27700), 'SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]' ) AS distance_m 
FROM aonb
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(357980.44 331724.97)', 27700) LIMIT 1;
```

Even with this query, I got the same error

```
ERROR:  BOOM! Could not generate outside point!
SQL state: XX000
```

Comment: is `geom` in lon/lat too or OSGB? ST_DistanceSpheroid takes lon/lat geoms as input not projected points.

Comment: @IanTurton The geometries are in OSGB. While I am currently able to obtain distance measurements using ST_Distance, I am attempting to use ST_DistanceSpheroid for more accurate results. However, it seems that this function takes lon/lat geometries as input and not projected points like OSGB. Is there any other solution for this then?

Comment: more accurate than what? most distances in GB will be calculated using Pythagoras on OSGB coordinates.

Comment: @IanTurton From the docs I came to know that ST_DistanceSpheroid gives more accurate distance in meters than ST_DistanceSphere https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html

Comment: Over long distances, not with in the UK

Comment: @IanTurton Alright, I will test with the two functions ST_DistanceSphere and ST_DistanceSpheroid for calculating the distances in meters within the UK and then compare the results.

Comment: much of that accuracy will depend on the exact transform you use to go to 4326 from 27700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html

> Returns minimum distance in meters between two lon/lat geometries given a particular spheroid.

Notice "between two lon/lat geometries". You must use ST_Transform and turn EPSG:27700 geometry into EPSG:4326, not the opposite as you do now.

Comment: It is working now. I just want to make sure if this is what you meant. @user30184

Comment: @Abhilash If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.

Comment: @TomazicM Yes I know, I am just waiting for user30184 response, to make sure if this is what the user meant.

Comment: @Abhilash the query in your comment is incorrect - the point coordinates you pass in as a literal are definitely not in degrees!

Comment: @geozelot, Yes you are correct. Here is the updated query . So instead of transforming the point, I should be transforming the geometry.  I have updated my query accordingly, and it now looks like this: "SELECT 
    name,
    ST_DistanceSpheroid(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326), 'SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]' ) AS distance_m 
FROM aonb
ORDER BY ST_Transform(geom, 4326) <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0363502486833616 52.688988284010456)', 4326) 
LIMIT 1;"

Comment: This query solved my problem. However it increased the execution time.

Comment: Your updated query is what I meant. If execution time is critical you may try to re-project the "aonb" table into EPSG:4326.

Comment: Alright. Understood.